# error in webpack compiling

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I've got an error while I'm trying to run my angular2 project. It occured after switching from PC with ubuntu to MacOS X. Node version: 7.7.4, npm version: 4.1.2. I'm running `npm webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --watch --port 8180` and then I'm getting this information:

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
69:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
85:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/angular2-focus/~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5889:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/angular2-focus/~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5905:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/Documents/Java/WORK/mediahelper/media-helper/src/main/web/node_modules/angular2-focus/node_modules/@angular/core/src/animation/animation_metadata_wrapped.d.ts:12:32 
Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

[...]

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:651:4 
All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:666:4 
All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:680:4 
All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:692:4 
All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers.

ERROR in [default] /Users/user/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:804:4 
All declarations of 'prototype' must have identical modifiers.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just updated my pet project to @angular4 and got similar warnings

```
angular/core.es5.js 5889:15-36 Critical dependency: 
the request of a dependency is an expression
```

Change your webpack.conf.js

```
from: /angular(\|/)core(\|/)(esm(\|/)src|src)(\|/)linker/
to:   /angular(\|/)core(\|/)@angular/
```

Link to reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/6160c2/angular_400_now_available/dfci3gm/